# How are some gradle dependencies working with no version supplied

Tags: gradle

As far as I know gradle requires a version number when setting dependencies, but partial wildcards are allowed. For example if I want Guava, I cannot do this as it fails:

```
compile('com.google.guava:guava')
```

It has to be (as an example):

```
compile('com.google.guava:guava:21.0')
```

However, I'm learning Spring, which has the following:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
compile("org.springframework:spring-web")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
```

How are these dependencies working with no version supplied?

Is it because of the following, but I thought these lines were required only for my plugin 'org.springframework.boot':

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is worth mentioning that the trick is called [BOM](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import) (*bill of materials*) and the actual versions can be checked in the related [POM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.7.0/spring-boot-dependencies-2.7.0.pom) file (in this example, it is for the version *2.7.0*) inside *spring-boot-dependencies* package. This is mentioned in the Spring Boot official documentation here: [Build Systems](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html).

Another way that Spring provides this (for non Boot projects) is through [Spring Platform BOM](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) where it actually provides version for [the following dependencies](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.6.0.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:Athens-SR2'
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm actually just starting reading through the boot reference guide to teach myself and never noticed this bit, I think I just skipped it given I have it working :)

Comment: You can find all the dependency versions it uses [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html)

Answer (score 16):

TL;DR - spring boot uses custom dependencies resolver.

A spring boot plugin that is applied with the following piece of code:

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

handles the dependencies that are listed without version. This logic is implemented in [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/dependencymanagement/DependencyManagementPluginFeatures.java) class which delegates it to [here](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/io/spring/gradle/dependencymanagement/DependencyManagementPlugin.java). `DependencyManagementPluginFeatures` are applied [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/plugin/SpringBootPlugin.java).

Comment: The links in this post no longer work. fyi

Answer (score 9):

The [spring boot gradle plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html) states the following:

> The version of the spring-boot gradle plugin that you declare
>   determines the version of the spring-boot-starter-parent bom that is
>   imported (this ensures that builds are always repeatable). You should
>   always set the version of the spring-boot gradle plugin to the actual
>   Spring Boot version that you wish to use.

Answer (score 7):

[Spring Boot Dependency Management Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) is not necessary.
You may use [build-in Gradle BOM support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) instead of [Spring Boot Dependency Management Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/)

For example:

```
    plugins {
        id 'java'
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.0.RELEASE')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    }
```

and for multi-module project:
in root **build.gradle** :

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.0.RELEASE'
}


allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

and in **core/build.gradle**

```
 dependencies {
    api platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.0.RELEASE')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```