# Gradle: Access version declaration in spring boot dependency-management plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, maven-bom

I have spring boot project and I try to use [spring boot dependency-management plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-dependency-management) to be able to use provided dependency versions.

The plugin 'simulates' mavens BOM behaviour, which means that it somehow retrieves versions of libs from maven parent project (I'm not sure how exatly this gets acheived, but generally versions are taken from [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml)). It does have `jackson.version` property that is used to setup versions for artifacts within `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat` group.

My project uses artifact from the same group, however it is not included into the BOM (`jackson-dataformat-yaml`) but I want to use the same jackson version.

I tried adding compile dependency like this:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:${jackson.version}"
```

but build fails with:

> Could not get unknown property 'jackson' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

**Q:** Is there a way to access the property? Or how else can I reuse the lib version?

**UPDATE**
I'm not sure why didn't I try this from the very beginning, but it works:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml"
```

However I have no clue why this works (the artifact is not declared anywhere).

Comment: Revising my answer to answer _why_ your updated solution works ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After question is updated with working example, I'll try to answer *why* it works without specifying the version instead:

The pom.xml you are referring to contains the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

... which refers to the following pom.xml in the jackson-bom project, which in turn contains the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version.dataformat}</version>
</dependency>
```

... which in turn specifies the version of the jackson-dataformat-yaml artifact...

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was a bit misleading, I updated the description. In fact the parent project is not standard gradle-parent project. Dependency management related functionality is achieved through spring boot plugin that imports versions declared in maven BOM. Generally `project.parent` will return null. You can find such config by generation a project here http://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 1):

> However I have no clue why this works (the artifact is not declared
>   anywhere).

So it is a concern that you are not using any version, but how it works?

Actually gradle use some rules. Those are given below:

1. Gradle will use **transitive dependency management** for specifying actual version.
2. On the other hand it will use **first level or second level hierarchy of repositories** to take the latest version.
3. From [spring documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/23/better-dependency-management-for-gradle),

> Maven’s dependency management includes the concept of a
>   bill-of-materials (bom). A bom is a special kind of pom that is used
>   to control the versions of a project’s dependencies and provides a
>   central place to define and update those versions.

For more you can go through this tutorial: [Gradle dependencies with jars that have no version number](http://programmingitch.blogspot.com/2011/07/gradle-dependencies-with-jars-that-have.html)

4. The [spring-boot-gradle-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html) is also available and provides tasks to create executable jars and run projects from source. It also provides [dependency management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-dependency-management) that, among other capabilities, **allows you to omit the version number** for any dependencies that are managed by Spring Boot:

> ```
> plugins {
>     id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.8.RELEASE'
>     id 'java'
> }
>
>
> repositories {
>     jcenter()
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
>     testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
> }
> ```

### Resource Link:

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html
2. [How are some gradle dependencies working with no version supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676534/how-are-some-gradle-dependencies-working-with-no-version-supplied)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when `.` (e.g. `${a.b}`) is used in string interpolation in groovy it treats being the precedes `.` as an object which has a property that follows `.`. So in `${a.b}` object `a` should have property `b` or it will fail. In you example `jackson` is an instance of `String` and it has no version property. To solve it you can use e.g. `jacksonVersion` or a `Map`. See a demo [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/46933310).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately It is not an option. First of all I have no control on parent project and can't change anything there. The second thing is that it is not standard parent project. In fact it is maven project and spring-boot gradle plugin makes it possible to import BOM from there (it takes versions from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml). 
You can generate such gradle project on http://start.spring.io/ and check.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota, sorry I feel like I may miss something. Could you please prepare a demo that reproduces the problem?