# Cannot resolve symbol for EnableEurekaServer in intelliJ. Yes I have the dependency/invalidated+restarted my IDE)

Tags: spring, gradle, intellij-idea, netflix-eureka

Im a beginner in Java so sorry in advance if I dont understand certain words.

I keep having the error: Cannot resolve symbol @EnableEurekaServer... When I manually type in the import line for eureka server, the word "cloud" is highlighted red in:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;
```

In my build.gradle file, I have

```
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server')
```

Why does this happen... Everything looks like it's supposed to work. I can provide screenshots of things if asked!

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My EurekaApplicationServer.java looks like this:

```
package com.example.eurekaserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
//import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaApplicationServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplicationServer.class, args);
    }

}
```

[picture of err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSTcs.png)

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think I added enough information. Would love some help

Comment: Changing the dependency to `compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server:1.0.0.RELEASE')` fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Ok... It worked. Jesus christ. Thank you so much man. It was such a simple fix too. Is there a reason why it does this though? I like to understand why things went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the dependency with the specific version, current version at the moment of this writing is:

```
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server:1.4.3.RELEASE')
```

You can find the latest available version number [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server).

For Spring Boot projects when you don't specify the dependency version, the special [dependency management](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) plug-in is used. For some reason it fails to provide the version for this specific dependency. See the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676534/how-are-some-gradle-dependencies-working-with-no-version-supplied).

Comment: Ahhh I see i see! thank you for explaining. Do you mind checking out this image and see if you can figure out why I am getting this error: https://imgur.com/a/5Dafv

Comment: work for after added last version in the dependency 
[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server] 
`<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
 <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to lower down the version of eureka-server/client.
The reason is that the maven repo cannot resolve the latest version of eureka server.To solve this, add repository to your pom/gradle file.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```

or

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
       <id>spring-milestones</id>
       <name>Spring Milestones</name>
       <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
       <snapshots>
           <enabled>false</enabled>
       </snapshots>
   </repository>
```